# Table's td with specified height doesn't work the same way on different browsers

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I need that every cell have the same fixed height and width.

So I have:

```
th, td {
    min-width: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    max-width: 110px;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

a td is just:

```
<td><span>*number*</span></td>
```

I was testing my code on Firefox 7 and I saw they OK but in Chrome/IE9 the cells are taller.

So:

With or without min-max height, the heights are:

FF7: 56px/60px (without borders / with borders)
Chrome: 62px/66px
IE9: 61px/65px

The problem is that I made a background for the TD on Photoshop and it's look weird if the size is not the right one and I don't know how to resolve it.

Outside this problem, chrome is acting weird. I Apply via Javascript some a to some td's once the page is loaded and they don't work on chrome... until you refresh sometimes.

**EDIT**: The table have fixed height and some border-spacing too.

**EDIT 2**: I made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFTpp/1/ The difference is less (58vs60) but is still different.

Comment: Have you added a poper (fully qualified) DOCTYPE to your page? IE switches to quirks mode rendering (including different box model) when you have no DOCTYPE specified

Comment: HTML 5 one, anyway, chrome is doing it wrong (or FF wrong, who knows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended changing the table for divs, more easy to archieve some results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed table layout:

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

Comment: That alone is not working, I mean, without touching anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following codes.

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:800px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col  style="width:200px; background:#CCC"/>
        <col  style="width:100px; background: #666"/>
        <col  style="width:500px; background: #000"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="height:100px">head</th>
        <th style="height:100px">&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="height:100px">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tfoot> 
      <tr>
        <td>foot</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot> 
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

You can adjust width of the any Column by changing the width of the `<col  style="width:200px;`. I just write the inline styles.